# Firebase Phone Authentication SMS Code null android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added `firebase` phone auth to my android project. First everything goes fine. After sometime, the sms code in `onVerificationCompleted()` is null.Thanks!!

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(mobileNumber, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, FirebasePhoneAuthActivity.this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        smsCode = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted: CODE " + smsCode);
        Log.i(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted: PROVIDER " + phoneAuthCredential.getProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCodeSent: CODE " + s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
        super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: " + s);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please can you check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth    or share code sample to investigate issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Instant Verification. In the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), it says:

> Instant verification: in some cases the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.

Also, if you look at the open-sourced [FirebaseUI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), [on this line of code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/phone/PhoneActivity.java#L178) it suggests that there is a possibility of verification being a success, while sms code being absent. Such a case would denote Instant Verification. So you can safely continue to use this credential to sign the user in.

Answer (score 1):

Gets the auto-retrieved SMS verification code if applicable. When SMS verification is used, you will be called back first via onCodeSent(String, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken), and later onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential) with a PhoneAuthCredential containing a non-null SMS code if auto-retrieval succeeded. If Firebase used another approach to verify the phone number and triggers a callback via onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential), then SMS code can be null