# Authentication Firebase by phone doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase, I'm trying to get the SMS code by phone number, but it doesn’t work. Everything does not work in two cases:

- Inside `onVerificationCompleted()` function with log message `sms code is null`.
- After visiting `startPhoneNumberVerification()` function logs stop writing and I don't receive SMS code either.

I read the documentation, looked at different versions of the code on Github, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

**VerificationFragment**

```kotlin
class VerificationFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var phone: String

    override val menuResId: Nothing? = null
    override val contentResId = R.layout.fragment_verification
    override val baseToolbar = R.id.toolbar

    private var verificationId = ""

    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onCodeSent(s: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, p1)
            verificationId = s
        }

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            val code = phoneAuthCredential.smsCode
            if (code != null) {
                Log.d("SmsCode", "onVerificationCompleted(): ща будем верифаить")
                verifyCode(code)
            } else {
                Log.d("SmsCode", "onVerificationCompleted(): sms code is null")
            }
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Log.d("SmsCode", "onVerificationFailed(): Invalid request")
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Log.d("SmsCode", "onVerificationFailed(): The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded")
            }
        }

    }

    private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
        Log.d("SmsCode", "startPhoneNumberVerification() visited")
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            baseActivity,
            callbacks
        )
    }

    fun verifyCode(code: String) {
        Log.d("SmsCode", "verificationId: $verificationId")
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code)
        singInWithCredential(credential)
    }

    private fun singInWithCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(baseActivity) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val fUser = task.result?.user
                    Log.d("SmsCode", "singInWithCredential(): fUser is $fUser")
                } else {
                    Log.d("SmsCode", "singInWithCredential(): error")
                }
            }
    }

    override fun setViews() {
        phone = VerificationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).phone
        setPhoneNumber()
        startPhoneNumberVerification(phone)
    }

    private fun setPhoneNumber() {
        verificationText.text = String.format(verificationText.text.toString(), phone)
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment**

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment: Fragment() {

    val baseActivity: MainActivity
        get() = activity as MainActivity

    private var currentView: View? = null

    protected abstract val menuResId: Int?
    protected abstract val contentResId: Int
    protected abstract val baseToolbar: Int

    protected inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(crossinline codeBlock: (T) -> Unit) {
        observe(this@BaseFragment, Observer { it -> it?.let { codeBlock(it) } })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        if (currentView == null) {
            currentView = inflater.inflate(contentResId, container, false)
        }
        return currentView!!
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setViews()
        setToolbar(view)
        setObservers()
        setListeners()
        setActions()
    }

    protected open fun setViews() {}

    protected open fun setObservers() {}

    protected open fun setListeners() {}

    protected open fun setActions() {}

    fun showBottomBar() = baseActivity.showBottomBar()

    fun hideBottomBar() = baseActivity.hideBottomBar()

    protected open fun setToolbar(view: View) {
        menuResId?.let {
            view.findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(baseToolbar).inflateMenu(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Adequate firebase messages do not appear in the logs. I have one test number, but I can’t get the SMS code to other numbers either.

I would be grateful for any answers.

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting the number? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade, yes, but this (Test phone number authentication without sending an actual SMS message) condition doesn't satisfy my desire to find out why the SMS code sent may be null

Answer (score 0):

You need firstly to enable phone authentication in firebase and then you can follow the code below :

```
public class VerifyPhoneNumActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected PinView editTextCode;
protected TextView resendCode;


DatabaseReference reference;

FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

String phone_number;

String code;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone_num);
    initView();


    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    phone_number = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");

    sendVerificationCode(phone_number);


    resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            sendVerificationCode(phone_number);


        }
    });




}


private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+20" + mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
}


private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks
        = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        //Getting the code sent by SMS
        code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

        //sometime the code is not detected automatically
        //in this case the code will be null
        //so user has to manually enter the code
        if (code != null) {
            editTextCode.setText(code);
            //verifying the code
            verifyVerificationCode(code);
        }
    }






    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {


        //  public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
       // Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneNumActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneNumActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.removeValue();

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        finish();

    }


};


private void verifyVerificationCode(String otp) {


    //signing the user


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());


    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("phone", phone_number);

    reference.updateChildren(map);


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneNumActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);


}


private void initView() {
    editTextCode = (PinView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
    resendCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resend_code);

}
```

}

and the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".controller.Register_Login.VerifyPhoneNumActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


<com.chaos.view.PinView
    android:id="@+id/editTextCode"
    style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textColor="#222222"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    app:cursorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:cursorWidth="2dp"
    app:itemCount="6"
    app:itemHeight="48dp"
    app:itemRadius="4dp"
    app:itemSpacing="5dp"
    app:itemWidth="36dp"
    app:lineColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:lineWidth="2dp"
    app:viewType="rectangle" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resend_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#019b77"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="@string/i_didn_t_get_a_code"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

I actually use phone number which I got from another but absolutely you can change this, hope it's helpful

Comment: Thank you, but authentication by phone number has already been enabled in the firebase, and the approaches that you used in your code were also used in mine

Comment: And it's still no answer on my question: "Why SMS code might be null in this case?"

Comment: I think this may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334262/firebase-phone-authentication-sms-code-null-android